# What is the easiest and lightest way to identify Indian visitors?

Tags: javascript, php, geoip

I can write all the necessary code in php or javascript, but what do I use? Geoip? Browser language? (which perhaps in india is: en) something else?

(I don't want to block access to the whole server, but to identify Indian visitors just in some functions of my sites)

Answer (score 0):

All methods you mentioned are all valid ways of identifying visitors, whether they are acurate or not is a different story. If you want the accuracy use a Geo identification API (ex: [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co), [ipinfo.io](https://ipdata.co), etc) although most are not free if you make over a certain amount of requests, but they do provide the most up to date and acurate location data.

If you use the javascript method of getting the browser language, then you'd loose out on accuracy since that is not based on their physical location, but it might be a good backup method.

The free and probably the best solution though is to download the MaxMind database and implement it yourself, although this will mean you need to update the database every so often to have the most up to date database.

You can download the database [here](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) and implement it with [this composer package.](https://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/)